# MySQL call parent from child

Tags: mysql

I have table which is as follows:

```
id      title   parent_id   editor
441     A       0           2
1093    B       18          2
18      C       0           0
3145    D       0           0
3144    E       0           8
3140    F       3130        22
3141    G       3130        335
3130    H       0           0
```

From the table, the title H with id 3130 have two children, there are title F with id 3140 and title G with id 3141.
So, if I want to call **b.editor = 22**, my expected output must be

```
a.id    a.title   a.parent_id   a.editor   b.id     b.title  b.parent_id    b.editor
3130    H         0             0          3140     F        3130           22
```

How do I make it happen?

Comment: What happens if there are more than two siblings?  Do we add more columns?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Yes, we'll add more columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id, a.title, a.parent_id, a.editor, b.id, b.title, b.parent_id, b.editor 
FROM test AS a
INNER JOIN test AS b 
ON a.id = b.parent_id
WHERE b.editor = 22
```